# Grouping Data Pipe not working

Tags: html, angular, pipe, grouping

I'm trying to get this group pipe to work but there seems to be an error with the html. The error says: TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined. When I locate the error it seems to be a problem with a line on the html.

JSON:

```
[
{
    "month": "2017-03-01",
    "modelVolume" [{
           "id": 1,
           "model": P213
    }]
}
{
    "month": "2017-03-01",
    "modelVolume" [{
           "id": 1,
           "model": P213
    }]
}
{
    "month": "2017-03-01",
    "modelVolume" [{
           "id": 1,
           "model": P213
    }]
}
{
    "month": "2017-03-01",
    "modelVolume" [{
           "id": 1,
           "model": P213
    }]
}
{
    "month": "2017-03-01",
    "modelVolume" [{
           "id": 1,
           "model": P213
    }]
}
{
    "month": "2017-03-01",
    "modelVolume" [{
           "id": 1,
           "model": P213
    }]
}
{
    "month": "2017-03-01",
    "modelVolume" [{
           "id": 1,
           "model": P213
    }]
}
{
    "month": "2017-03-01",
    "modelVolume" [{
           "id": 1,
           "model": P213
    }]
}
{
    "month": "2017-03-01",
    "modelVolume" [{
           "id": 1,
           "model": P213
    }]
}]
```

This is the HTML code where the problem seems to be:

```
       <ul>
            <li *ngFor="let group of volumes | GroupByPipe">{{group.month}}
              <ul>
                <li *ngFor="let event of group.modelVolumes">{{event.id}} {{event.model}}</li>
              </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

This is the Pipe:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from "@angular/core";

@Pipe({name: 'GroupByPipe'})
export class GroupByPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(collection: Array<any>, property: string = 'month'): Array<any> {
        if(!collection) {
            return null;
        }
        const gc = collection.reduce((previous, current)=> {
            if(!previous[current[property]]) {
                previous[current[property]] = [];
            }
                current.volumes.forEach(x => previous[current[property]].push(x));
            return previous;
        }, {});
        return Object.keys(gc).map(volume => ({ month: volume, modelVolumes: gc[volume] }));
    }
}
```

Comment: is the json structure of volumes is same as given above ? Shoun't this be `property: string = 'month'`

Comment: Done that change. Still got the error and it's still not working.

Comment: The error seems to be here: `current.volumes.forEach`. Where is `volumes` defined? Consider strongly typing your data with an interface and using that interface to type your incoming array.

Comment: Your JSON looks invalid. Try updating your `volumes` array to `[{"month": "2017-03-01","modelVolume": [{"id": 1,"model":"P213"}]},{"month": "2017-03-01","modelVolume": [{"id": 1,"model":"P213"}]}]`